# how do get rowindex from Gridview Textbox in focus event in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using Textbox in Gridview by using templatefield. All are working well. But my problem is that, whenever the textbox get the focus, i need that rowindex of that gridview.
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this [DataGridViewCell.RowIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex.aspx)

```
private void getCurrentCellButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  string msg = String.Format("Row: {0}, Column: {1}",
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex,
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);
  MessageBox.Show(msg, "Current Cell");
}
```